# Oracle equivalent for Sybase query

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe

```
update Asset_Table 
set P.Asset = L.Asset ,
 P.Update_By = 'BATCH_JOB' ,
 P.Update_Ts =  datediff(ss,'01/01/1970',getdate()),
 P.Machine_Name = 'PENTA'  
 from Asset_table  P , RateDB..User_Asset L
 where P.User_Id     =L.User_Id
 and  L.process_status = 'WIP'
 and upd_ins_del_flag = 'U'   and process_pid = 2
```

The above is a sybase query.Can anyone help me the equivalent of this query in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that's (obviously) different is the calculation of the Unix timestamp:

```
(SYSDATE - to_date('19700101','YYYYMMDD')) * 86400
```

id the Oracle equivalent of

```
datediff(ss,'01/01/1970',getdate())
```

But Oracle won't be too happy with a table called "RateDB..User_Asset"

Comment: Also, Oracle won't let you Update t Set ... with a From/Where clause.